# How do I disable the "Select input method" Notification?

Tags: keyboard, notifications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I don't know if this is standard ICS behavior or if it's due to my Cyanogenmod based ROM, but every time I open the soft keyboard by clicking on a text box/area a notification appears in the notification drawer that says "Select input method."  I don't mind seeing this notification one time, but I'm already using the input method I want and I'd like to disable the notification.

Is this standard behavior for Ice Cream Sandwich? Can it be disabled?

Comment: Do you have an external keyboard paired/plugged in or anything of that sort? That's the only time I've seen it appear, personally.

Comment: No I don't.  I'm using just my phone and nothing else, and there's no hardware keyboard on my particular phone (Droid Bionic)

Comment: Why do you want to disable the notification?

Comment: Setting -> Notifications ->Android System -> Virtual keyboard; Works at least on Galaxy S10, Android 11.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a standard 'feature' of ICS. Aside from the notification, changing input methods can be accomplished through the "language and input" section of the phone menu. If you disable and uninstall all keyboards except for one, so there is nothing else to switch to, the notification may disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is true. The only way to disable it is to run a custom ICS ROM that the ability to disable it (a few do).

Comment: Ha that's kinda lame.  I guess I have my answer then.

Comment: I'm not sure about stock ICS, but in CyanogenMod 9 there is a toggle that allows you to hide this notification.  I will post this as a separate answer.

Comment: If you only have one method to select from, I believe it goes away. Go to `Settings -> Language & Input` and uncheck all but one input method.

Comment: I am using alternative keyboard and can't disable the default. Which means I have two I input methods. Thus I can't get rid of notification. Sucks...

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov If you're rooted you can just uninstall/disable the stock keyboard. You can disable even if you're not rooted.

Comment: @LiamW: Can't disable it on my Samsung S III. The checkbox in the "Language and input" (in Settings) is checked and grayed out. My phone is not rooted.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov The stock Android keyboard cannot be unselected, sorry.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov You can not uncheck it, but you can disable by Settings ->Apps ->All ->Google Keyboard ->Disable ->OK

Comment: Unfortunately @András you cannot do this for the Samsung Keyboard, if you prefer to keep the Google Keyboard.  There is only a  Force Stop option.

Comment: If only GBoard supported Korean, I wouldn't have to have a second keyboard installed. But I do and there's nothing I can do?

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure about stock ICS, but in CyanogenMod 9 & 10.2 you can disable this notification by going to "Settings -> Language & input" and de-selecting the "Selector notification" option just below the list of keyboards.

Comment: I'm using CM 11 and no longer have this option :(

Comment: @Ben CM 11 is still a work in progress.  Most of the CM 10.2 features are currently being forward-ported, and should eventually re-appear.  Give it some time.

Comment: I confirm that CM11 does have this option now, and also most ROMs that are based on it.

Comment: This option is also present in Paranoid Android (4.6 BETA 1)

Answer (score 14):

Go into language settings and disable(uncheck) all of the other keyboards but the one you wish to use. go to applications settings, find the "all" tab, find the other stock keyboards and disable them. restart. worked for me.

Comment: This should definitely be marked as correct answer, IMO. On my stock ICS GNexus, I did this (while leaving my Google voice keyboard option enabled), and once I restarted, the icon no longer appears. Finally!

Comment: Just a note, this doesn't seem to work with JB 4.2. :/

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine on my Google Nexus 4 running Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 8):

This is a feature in ICS and above. Its goal is to make it easy to switch input methods.

It only appears if you have more than one IME enabled. The sad thing is that if you use a non-stock keyboard this will **always** appear.

If you want to get rid of it simply go into

```
Settings -> Apps -> All (tab)
```

and find the default keyboard(s). Open the entry and choose disable.

Comment: What's "the default keyboard" called?

Comment: Google Keyboard is the name for Nexus devices for example.

Comment: This worked just fine on my non-rooted phone, using (customly installed) Gboard input.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is standard behavior in ICS. This appears if you have more than one keyboard selected in the ICS keyboard & language settings page, which is always the case if you use a third party keyboard. Some custom roms (particularly CM9 and AOKP) allow you to disable it in their extra settings.

Answer (score 2):

On Xperia devices you can disable this by disabling the "Smart Keyboard" option in
`Settings->Xperia->Smart Keyboard`.

Comment: Cannot find this on my Z5 Compact.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to backup, then uninstall "Android keyboard"

Answer (score 1):

> 1. You DON'T need to be rooted to do this. The "Disable" function is part of Android, it does not delete the app. Disable can also be used
>      to turn off bloatware apps if your squeamish about rooting to get rid
>      of them. It does however stop the app from working at all, so be sure
>      that its not used or connected to any of the apps you use. Unlike
>      using root and Titanium Backup to delete or "freeze" an app, Disabling
>      will not keep you from being able to take any updates. When the update
>      checks the app will still be there, just turned off
> 2. System Settings-->Language & Input Go down to the Keyboard & Input Methods section and uncheck everything but the keyboard that you plan
>      to use, including "Google voice typing" and "moto Chinese input" (for
>      me that means leaving Swiftkey checked). having only one checked
>      should stop the notification. However on the Bionic there are two
>      input methods that the checkmark is blocked out on so you can't
>      uncheck them: the stock keyboard and Swype. These two are what would
>      keep the stupid notification coming back. So you need to go turn the
>      things off manually in apps.​
> 3. System Settings-->Apps-->All-->Android Keyboard (AOSP)-->Disable-->OK System
>      Settings-->Apps-->All-->Swype-->Disable-->OK As far I know disabling
>      these shouldn't mess with any other apps on your phone if you have
>      another keyboard installed from the market, so don't worry about the
>      notification that pops up when you hit "Disable".If you are worried
>      about it...then you'll have to live with the notification. If
>      something down the road does cause you a problem and you think this is
>      it then just go back to apps-->all, scroll all the way down, and hit
>      "Enable", then reboot and you should be good to go. If you use one of
>      these two instead of a third party keyboard I'm sure you could just
>      disable the other one and get the notification to go away.
> 4. Power off and reboot your device.
> 5. Open up texting and test that when you select the input field A) you don't get a notification and B) That a keyboard shows up at all
>      :icon_eek: If you don't get a keyboard at all don't panic, there's
>      just one more step to do.If you still get a notification go back to
>      step one and make sure that any other keyboards are unchecked. ​
> 6. System Settings-->Language & Input-->Default-->Select your keyboard (for me this is Swiftkey) Your keyboard of choice should be the only
>      option in this list, select it and then go test to make sure
>      everything works right.

[Source](http://www.droidforums.net/threads/input-method-notification-removal-no-root.242692/)

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings > Language and Input and uncheck Google Voice Typing.

Answer (score -3):

If all else fails just disable the stock Google search (which automatically reactivates Google voice typing & therefore 'select input method') and use Google search from a downloaded app.  Yahoo or Bing can also be replacement search engines.