# How do I get the "Change keyboard" notification to go away for more than an hour?

Tags: notifications, keyboard, 7.0-nougat, input-methods, swiftkey

I have Swiftkey installed.

I get a notification all the time about choosing my keyboard. I can get it to go away for a short time by selecting

```
Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Current keyboard
```

Then selecting Swiftkey. But the notification comes back 30-60 mins later (I haven't timed it).

How do I get this to stop showing up? [There are instructions on the Swiftkey site](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201644832-I-keep-getting-a-notification-saying-Choose-input-method-) that are either outdated or don't apply to my phone: the settings don't look like that.

[The relevant AE answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19566/how-do-i-disable-the-select-input-method-notification) is 5 years old.

LG G5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now all i can see is there are only 2 possible solutions 
1) keep only one keyboard as suggested in 5 year old question
 
2) or keep all keyboards but disable all except for the one that you use by going to **setting->language & input->virtual keyboard->manage keyboards**, here **disable** all except one that you use regularly 
 
Tried and tested on stock nougat 7.0 on moto g5+

Comment: "virtual keyboard": my phone does not have this. I have "Keyboard & Input methods" and there is no "Manage keyboards" option in that group.

Comment: Try finding somewhere in language and input setting it should be there else you have only 1st above stated solution left